# My Logitech K800 keyboard stopped typing one letter How do I fix it when rebooting didn't work?

Tags: keyboard

I've been using the Logitech K800 keyboard with my Windows 10 desktop for a couple of years and now it has stopped typing one specific letter.

I've rebooted computer; I've unplugged keyboard for 30 seconds and plugged it back in. I've cleaned all around the keys with a soft brush.

What else can I do to get it to work?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. Keyboards can fail in the way you describe.

Comment: Can you maybe tell us what specific letter it is? I assume it is none of the letters used to type out this question, correct? Regardless, keyboards like that are considered commodity items and if they break? Best to just buy a new replacement.

Comment: Why not test it in another system? While I agree with others that it is probably a hardware problem, it is also possible that somehow you have configured it as a hotkey that does nothing.

Comment: does the failing key feel different from all of the other keys?

Comment: 1. Try "canned air" to clean *under* the key. 2. Apparently, the key caps easily pop off, and you can try cleaning underneath. See Videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaY8otYwnfI, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Az3JoKNZuc and you likely can find others.

Answer (score 0):

That key failed.

If it's a mechanical one, and you happen to have a soldering iron and some soldering skills, you can try removing and soldering another keyswitch. More likely you should buy a new keyboard.